# Testing python project with Tox and Teamcity

Tags: python, teamcity, pytest, tox

I have project with very simple configuration matrix, described in `tox`: `py{27,35}-django{18,19}`

I'm using TeamCity as the CI-server, run tests with `py.test` with installed `teamcity-messages`. I've tried to run every configuration like `tox -e py27-django18` in different steps. But Teamcity didn't summarize tests <s>and didn't accumulate coverage for files, it's only count coverage for last run</s> and `Tests passed:​ ...` show tests from only one build.

How testing with multiple Python configurations can be integrated into Teamcity?

upd. Find out, that coverage counts correctly, just forgot to add `--cov-append` option to `py.test`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TeamCity counts the tests based on their names. My guess is since your tests in the tox matrix have the same name, they are counted as one test. This should be visible on the test page of your build, where you can see invocation counts of each test.

For TeamCity to report number of tests correctly, test names must differ in different configurations. Perhaps, you could include configuration details in the reported test name